# How to get the checksum of an Array of object in Java

Tags: java, checksum

How to calculate the checksum of the array of objects in Java, basically trying to send the checksum from the client to the server, client will calculate the checksum of `arr`, and send it to server, server will calculate the checksum of its local data. For example, I have the following code:

```
public class Test {

    public int age;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testHash();
    }

    public static void testHash(){
        Test test1 = new Test();
        Test test2 = new Test();
        Test test3 = new Test();

        test1.age = 23;
        test2.age = 123;
        test3.age = 3;


        Test[] arr={test1, test2, test3};
    }

}
```

How to get the checksum of the `arr`? And if the data is the same on both client and server, the checksum should be same, are there any ways of caclulate the checksum is the same if the data on client and server is the same?

Comment: Is the order of the elements in the array important?

Comment: Lookup Array.deepHashCode function

Comment: what *is* the checksum? There is no predefined formula.

Comment: @schtever no the order is not important

Comment: @OldProgrammer I checked the deepHashCode, but not sure if it will generate the same value for the same data on client and server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

overridde `hashCode()` in `Test` class

```
public class Test {

    public int age;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return age;
    }

}
```

sort the array first then call `Arrays.deepHashCode()`

```
Test[] arr={test1, test2, test3};
Arrays.sort(arr, (t1,t2)-> {return t1.age - t2.age;});
int hash = Arrays.deepHashCode(arr);
```

you will get the same result on both server and client.